# How to replace an existing MySQL installation into a MySQL cluster?

Tags: mysql, rdbms, web-development-server, mysql-cluster

If I have a database created in MySQL RDBMS, which is being used for running a website. After sometime, I notice that there is a potential increase in traffic and therefore I need more servers to hold the data. So I think of clustering as one of the option. Now, how will I be able to replace the existing database application into MySQL cluster without losing data and without getting the website down?